# How to know which tab is selected in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qvboxlayout

I have multiple tabs in an application using Qt and I add them all to a `QVBoxLayout` object. How to know which one is selected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`QTabWidget::currentIndex()` will return the index of the active tab.

Comment: should I use it exactly like or using the Tab object because I already tried it like objTab->(..) there no currenIndex method ??

Comment: @Engine - no, this is the actual method, you will use that on your instance. If you have a Designer UI form you will need to do something like `ui->myTabWidget.currentIndex()` or without the `ui->` if you instantiate the user interface programmatically.

Comment: It's a method of QTabWidget, not of individual tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `ui->QTabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->Tab`
In case you rearrange your tabs and the index changes.